# Logging configuration with subprocesses

Tags: python, logging, subprocess

I have a python script with logging configuration that is called with `subprocess.call` from a main script. I would like the subprocess to create the log file, and write to it, as it is configured in the subprocess's code. In addition, I would like to see the logs also displayed in the main process' console output.

The following works on mac, but doesn't work on a linux box with python 3.10.4

**Main Code**

```
import subprocess
import logging


log_format = '%(asctime)s :: %(name)s :: %(levelname)-8s :: %(message)s'
log_streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler()
logging.basicConfig(format=log_format, level=logging.INFO, 
                    handlers=[log_streamhandler])
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    code = subprocess.call(["python3", "my_subprocess.py"])
    logger.info(f'Subprocesses completed with code {code}')
```

**my_subprocess.py**

```
import sys
import logging


if __name__ == '__main__':

    log_format = '%(asctime)s :: %(name)s :: %(levelname)-8s :: %(message)s'
    log_filehandler = logging.FileHandler('my_subprocess.log')
    log_streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    logging.basicConfig(format=log_format, level=logging.INFO, 
                        handlers=[log_filehandler, log_streamhandler])
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    logger.info('Starting subprocess.')
    logger.info('Completed subprocess.')
```

The reason why I create the log file from the subprocess, is because it also needs to be able to run on its own, and create the log file. Several such subprocesses are called by the main process. How can I restructure to keep these features and run on linux as expected?

Comment: What error are you get ? Is it `AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'run'` ?

Comment: No error, just the log files are empty if running on linux. I have been actually using the `call`, just experimented with the `run` for a while. Let me change to `call` in the post. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: I will rename the subprocess file in the example not to have a clash with the standard package name.

Comment: Is problem solved ?

Comment: Thanks for checking in. Not solved, I just updated how the problem is presented in the question. The issue is that the log file is empty on the linux somehow with this code.

Comment: Apparently the problem is solved. There might have been some update to the server in the meanwhile. It's unknown what caused the problem. of empty files.